# Selection for strings with escaping characters

Tags: regex, powershell, windows-10, escaping, select-string

The following code, somehow, does what I want, except for certain lines that contain `\` and another problem. I'd like to clear up first the inconvenient concerning the defective selection for strings containing `\`.

```
$FC=(gc E3.txt)
$L=$FC.length
$SERI=foreach($k in 0..($L-1)) {$FC[$k]}
$list='E4.txt'                        # initially, no content
foreach($x in $SERI){sls -path E0.txt -pattern $x  -CaseSensitive |ac $list}
$SCH=(gc $list).Replace('E0.txt:','') 
clc $list
ac $list $SCH
```

Below is found the content of the 3 files.

```
 E3 (input 2)                   E0 (input 1)                           E4 (output)
_ahg                         _ab \> croitre\\                       2:_cnur \> plein\\
_cnur                        _cnur \> plein\\                       4:_cnv \> pratique\\                  
_cnv                         _cho \> cartouche\\                    7:_cob \> plaque\\                  
_co\m u                      _cnv \> pratique\\                     9:_coe \> étang (\!\!: stn: taief)\\
_co\upp m                    _co\m u \> lequel\\                                      
_cob                         _co\upp m \> des morceaux\\                     
_coe                         _cob \> plaque\\                                               
                             _drj \> complet\\                        
                             _coe \> étang (\!\!: stn: taief)\\
                             _coi \> prairie\\
```

I expected for lines such as `_co\m u \> lequel\\` to be selected, but instead they result in an error statement, as shown below for the present line.

```
sls : La chaîne _co\m u  n’est pas une expression régulière valide : analyse de "_co\m u " - Séquence d'échappement \m non reconnue.
Au caractère Ligne:7 : 20
+ ... ($x in $lt){sls -path E0.txt -pattern $x  - ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Select-String], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegex,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

Could modifications be made to that code to make it work?

Comment: `$SERI = foreach ($k in 1..$($FC.Count -1)) { [regex]::Escape($FC[$k]) }`

Comment: @JosefZ Seems to work fine, thanks; you should turn that comment into an answer, with a couple of explanations maybe, that way you'd get your points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `E3.txt` file contains regex metacharacters. *The following characters are reserved*: `[]().\^$|?*+{}` (see [About Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7#escaping-characters)). Use

### either

`-SimpleMatch` parameter in [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7) as follows (*it prevents interpreting the value of the `Pattern` parameter as a regular expression statement*):

```
foreach( $x in $SERI ) {
    Select-String -Path E0.txt -Pattern $x -SimpleMatch -CaseSensitive |
    Add-Content $list
}
```

### or

`[regex]::Escape()` static method as follows:

```
$SERI = foreach ($k in 1..$($FC.Count -1)) { [regex]::Escape( $FC[$k] ) }
```

For explanation, read in (`.NET`) [Regex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8#methods) article:

> [**Escape(String)** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Escape_System_String_)
>
> Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,
>   ., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This
>   instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters
>   literally rather than as metacharacters.

For instance (see the *5th line* in the `E3.txt` file): `[regex]::Escape('_co\upp m')` returns `_co\\upp\ m`.